# Is there a way to transfer to another branch after being a Navy nuke?

Tags: job-change, united-states

I am about to become a nuke in the US Navy. It's a great program but it only fulfills part of my interest. I am wondering if there is a way to transfer to another branch of the military and be retrained, for instance as an Army Ranger or perhaps a Marine, after serving a full enlistment in the navy nuclear program? I'm ok with the idea of starting over at a lower place on the totem pole but it would be nice to keep my paygrade and progress towards the 20 year retirement.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do a search online for OSVET or 'Other Services Veteran'. This is the general program for enlisted service members to migrate to other branches.

Comment: Hey Andrew. What do you mean by nuke? The only meaning I know for it is large nasty bomb... :)

Comment: Presumably navy slang for someone in the nuclear program -- which I'm guessing is mostly power plants rather than bombs.

Comment: (I do wonder whether there's a T-shirt or bumper sticker proudly boasting that the Navy gets a lot of nuke -e.)

Comment: @keshlam don't forget the nuclear submarines...

Comment: @mkennedy: That's power plant, essentially. Unless you're talking about warheads, in which case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can switch branches assuming the "gaining" branch has room for you, you qualify physically/mentally for the position you'd be looking to enter. You'll want to check with a recruiter for the branch you'd like to switch to as early as possible though. There are some paperwork "hoops" you'll need to jump through, and you may need to perform cross training depending on how much of your current training will cross over.

You will also need to be prepared to "re-attend" basic training. I'm not sure if it'll be a requirement (some of the services don't require it as I recall), but it may well be the price of entry.

I've attached a link with some preliminary information, but you should talk to your personnel division for more details. A recruiter will also be able to help.

http://www.militaryspot.com/career/changing-branches/

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick and informative amswer. This was exactly what I was looking for.